# How to resolve parameters passed to the console app on a Startup class while using DI

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a console app that is using dependency injection. I am struggling on how to resolve the **args** parameters that I am passing to the console. Also I would like to get them as a **string[]** as they are passed on Main

This is my Program.cs

```
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

                    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                    builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", true);

                    if (args != null)
                        builder.AddCommandLine(args);

                    IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
                    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>((sp) => configuration);

                   services.AddTransient<IStartupService, StartupService>();
               ).UseConsoleLifetime()
                .Build();

            var svc = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<StartupService>(host.Services);
            svc.Run();
        }
}
```

My TranslationFileService looks like this

```
public class StartupService : IStartupService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public StartupService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        //I need to resolve the args here
    }
}
```

now I don't like to run the cmd using donet run.... I am more inclined to use it with the nameofApp.exe param1 param2. With that said, I don't know how to resolve the parameters correctly. There is a CommandLineProvider that has all of them that is part of the Configuration object when I run it, but how can I Resolve that instance at this point or how can I get the original parameters?

Comment: what are you trying to do? when you call builder.AddCommandLine(args); they just become part of the IConfiguration object

Comment: how I get them on the Run method then?

Comment: from your _configuration

Comment: here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.commandlineconfigurationextensions.addcommandline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: also:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: you will need to run dotnet run .... also check that I want to pass my parameters consoleapp.exe param1 param2